# Regex for java split of whitespaces, numbers and operators, but keep operators and numbers

Tags: java, regex, split, operators

So far I've got this regex to split my string into a string array by splitting and removing whitespaces, and also splitting by operator but keeping the operator and inserting into the same array.

`tokens = rpn.split("(?<=\\s) |(?=\\s) |(?>\\s+) |(?<=[-+*/()])|(?=[-+*/()])|(?>=[-+*/()])");`

```
E.g. input 2 3 + OR 2 3+;
     output a[0]=2;a[1]=3;a[2]=+
```

This is for a RPN calculator to remove all whitespaces and seperate numbers and operators.

The above regex works to split up numbers and operators `e.g. 3+ into 3 + but if I have 2 3 +`
then the output is`tokens[0]=2; tokens[1]=3;tokens[2]="";tokens[3]=+;`

Please anyone help solve this regex problem.

Comment: Sorry, could you try clarify what it is your want? Post a few cases of `input` -> `output`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
tokens = rpn.replaceAll("(?=\\p{Punct})|(?<=\\p{Punct})", " ").split("\\s+");
```

This adds spaces around punctuation and then splits on that whitespace. You can replace `\\p{Punct}` with a more specific set of punctuation, such as the `[-+*/()]` in your example if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Split .... I tried it with the following regex:

```
\s*(?=[^0-9.]+)\s*
```

Split on any point where the next character is not a number (with decimal). You will probably have to be smart about whether numbers can be negative (which would require a ahange to your data format anyway)

Edit: I tested it in perl ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can perform your splitting like this.

```
public String[] split(String text) {
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d+|[\\+\\-*/])").matcher(text);
    int idx = 0;
    while (matcher.find(idx)) {
        a.add(matcher.group());
        idx = matcher.end();
    }
    return a.toArray();
}

public void testSplit() {
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"3", "+", "5", "*", "3", "-", "4"},
            split("3 + 5 * 3-4"));
}
```

It's clearer and much more understandable than monstous regular expression.